# Content Security Policy doesn't allow mixed content

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest

I am trying to access an internal machine of my network via chrome extensions. I am calling a php file from my chrome extension. I am using manifest file as follows:

```
{
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "js": [ "lib/jquery.js", "lib/jquery-ui.js", "lib/util.js" ],
      "matches": [ "*://plus.example.com/*", "*://tools.example.com/*" ]
   }, {
      "js": [ "tools/g_tool.js" ],
      "matches": [ "*://plus.example.com/*" ]
   }, {
      "js": [ "tools/b_tool.js" ],
      "matches": [ "*://tools.google.com/*" ]
   } ],
   "icons": {
      "128": "images/icon_128.png",
      "16": "images/icon_16.png",
      "48": "images/icon_48.png"
   },
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Tool",
   "permissions": [ "*://plus.example.com/*", "*://tools.example.com/*", "http://myusername-example.com/*"],
   "version": "0.7",
   "web_accessible_resources": [ "images/loading.gif" ]
}
```

The internal machine which I am using can be used only via http. So, I am looking around for a way to use it in my chrome extension.

Comment: And the problem is...

Comment: The [default extension CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html) does not restrict XHR requests. Those are restricted by the `permissions` array. Assuming you have the host/IP of the internal machine listed in `permissions` something else is going wrong. You should explicitly include any error messages you are getting in this question.